# Help - calculation of a multivariable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Can we prove that $  \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2 y^2(y-x)}{x^3+y^3}=0$ without using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition?

My original idea was to use polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$.

Then :
$$\lim_{ r\to 0^+}\frac{r^5( \cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta)(\sin\theta -\cos\theta)}{r^3(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta)} = \lim_{r \to 0^+} r^2\frac{( \cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta)(\sin\theta -\cos\theta)}{\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta}.$$

Now i think the problem is that the expression inside the limit isnt bounded ( for $\theta= -\pi/4 \rightarrow \infty$).

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: Alright, thanks !

Comment: You *can't* prove it, with or without a $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Answer (score 3):

The limit does not exist and you are right, the direction $\theta=-\pi/4$ is the critic one. Restrict the function along the curve $y=-x+x^3$ (its tangent line at $(0,0)$ is $y=-x$), then, as $x\to 0$,
$$f(x,-x+x^3)=\frac{x^2 (-x+x^3)^2(-x+x^3-x)}{x^3+(-x+x^3)^3}
=\frac{-2x^5+o(x^5)}{3x^5+o(x^5)}\to -\frac{2}{3}.$$
You can also consider the more general curve $y=-x+x^a$ with $a>1$ and choose a suitable value of the exponent $a$ in order to obtain a limit different from $0$.